# Magento2: How to use the Form Field Render for Weight Field?

Tags: magento2

I'd like information on the following :

How to use the Form Field Render for Weight Field?

How to Add Custom Field in Magento Tab ?

See In the Magento catalog that displays some customization to the Weight field as display formatting of the value to 2 decimal places and UNIT Measure